# Raphael JS : mouseover/mouseout - problem with text-labels

Tags: label, mouseover, raphael, mouseout

I use Raphael JS to create an SVG-map with area's and textlabels. I want the area to highlight when you move the mouse over it.

I have this working now, but when I move the mouse over the label (in the center of the area) the mouseout-event for that area is triggered, so the area is unhighlighted again.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening, or a workaround ?

Comment: I use jQuery with **mousenter** and **mouseleave** and it "works well enough for SVG" (use `raphaelElement.node`). It may or may not work with IE/VML.

Answer (score 5):

Create a rect with opacity set to 0 over the text and attach the event handlers on that rect. You can calculate the dimensions of the rect using `getBBox()` of the text.

Comment: the area's are polygons, so a rect is not good enough. But I found I can probably use set's for this. I create a set of each area + label, and attach the event handler to the set, instead of to the area

Answer (score 2):

Creating a set via [Paper#set](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.set) was the approach that worked for me.  e.g.:

```
var st = paper.set();

st.push.apply(st, vectors);  // `vectors`: my array of "hoverable" vectors
st.push(text);               // `text`:    my text vector for `vectors`

st.hover(function () {
    text.show();
}, function () {
    text.hide();
});
```