# SVG : how to properly handle mouseover and mouseout event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, mouseevent, raphael

I'm using Raphael js framework to create interactive svg image on client:

```
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("svgcontainer"));
var path = paper.path("M0,0 L150,0 L150,150, L0,150 Z");

path.attr({fill: 'red'});

var text = paper.text(40,20, "some text");

path.mouseover(function(){this.attr({fill: 'green'})});
path.mouseout(function(){this.attr({fill: 'red'})});
```

Please look at jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/6BtUk/9/

If the user moves the mouse over the text inside the `path` element, the `path` element will trigger `mouseout` event. How to prevent triggering of mouseout event on `path` element when user moves mouse to text element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't worked with Raphael but it looks like you can try using [Set](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Set) to group your label and the rectangle and attach the event handler to the set.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yDqt/)

Here is another question that is similar to yours

[Raphael JS : mouseover/mouseout - problem with text-labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362849/raphael-js-mouseover-mouseout-problem-with-text-labels)